# Pulling from the same data position from multiple arrays in bash

Tags: arrays, bash

BACKGROUND

What I'm trying to do here is read from a file that has PID information and separate the columns out into arrays. I have completed this part already, though I think is a better way than what I currently have (catting the same file 4 times).

```
pid=( $(cat /tmp/deadpidlist.log | awk -F " " '{print $1}') )
cpu=( $(cat /tmp/deadpidlist.log | awk -F " " '{print $2}') )
mem=( $(cat /tmp/deadpidlist.log | awk -F " " '{print $3}') )
ctime=( $(cat /tmp/deadpidlist.log | awk -F " " '{print $4}') )
```

WHAT AM I DOING? oh god

After that, I need to loop through each PID and if the pid fits the criteria I am looking for, put the corresponding cpu usage, memory usage and cpu time beside it in a file and then email that file out.

```
for i in "${pid[@]}"
do
...
    if grep -Fxq "$pattern" /tmp/or_report.log; then
            echo "$i" >> /tmp/deadpidwalking.log
```

I have the rest of my code up on a gist here: https://gist.github.com/sithtoast/e1654adab3cceb137ba2

Thanks!

Comment: +1 for documenting your inner critic! You might consider a method to transpose the file before reading and storing the fields in arrays (search "transpose a file in bash")

Comment: @SithToast from your avatar I see that you really like cats, don't you? But `pid=( $(awk -F " " '{print $1}' /tmp/deadpidlist.log) )` really is enough.

Comment: @ jimmmij Is it that obvious? Haha. Thanks for the shortcut!

Answer (score 1):

A simple loop in `bash` should be sufficient. Note the rarely seen use of subscripted arrays as arguments to `read`.

```
declare -a pid cpu mem ctime
i=-1
while ((i++)); read "pid[i]" "cpu[i]" "mem[i]" "ctime[i]" and_the_rest; do
:
done < /tmp/deadpidlist.log
```

A more straightforward loop would be

```
declare -a pid cpu mem ctime
while read a b c d and_the_rest; do
    pid+=("$a")
    cpu+=("$b")
    mem+=("$c")
    ctime+=("$d")
done < /tmp/deadpidlist.log
```

Comment: Youre an fast-typer :) - The 1st solution is very nice!

Comment: If the log file has more than four fields then don't forget to add a field to the `read` to absorb the tail.

Answer (score 0):

For the 1st part:

```
while read -r ipid icpu imem ictime icmd
do
        pid+=($ipid)
        cpu+=($icpu)
        mem+=($imem)
        ctime+=($ictime)
        cmd+=($icmd)
done < /tmp/deadpidlist.log
```

Some small comments for the gist:

Use functions. You can save much typing redirecting the output from a function - like:

```
some() {
    echo some
    cat /some/file
}
#later
some >> /some/outfile
```

also, you can save many `echo` with grouping them into one `heredoc`

```
some2() {
cat - <<EOF
some output what want
can use $variables
$(date) #command substitutions too
EOF
}
```

If you don't want variable expansions, use the `heredoc` as `<<'EOF'`

Also, you can use

```
let countertwo++  #instead of countertwo=$((countertwo + 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use associative arrays for cpu, mem, and ctime.  Also, read the input all in one pass via the `read` builtin.

```
declare -a pid
declare -A cpu
declare -A mem
declare -A ctime

while read this_pid this_cpu this_mem this_ctime tail; do
  pid[${#pid[*]}]=$this_pid
  cpu[$this_pid]=$this_cpu
  mem[$this_pid]=$this_mem
  ctime[$this_pid]=$this_ctime
done < /tmp/deadpidlist.log

for i in "${pid[@]}" do;
  # ...
  echo $i cpu[$i] mem[$i] ctime[$i]
done
```